# linked list index method-java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, comparable

I am having trouble writing a finalIndexOf method, which should return the index in the current object list of the last element that equals the parameter element, meaning that duplicate elements are okay. E.g. if the linkedlist had 2,4,4,5,6,7,7,7 and finalIndexOf(4) is called, 2 should be returned as the last 4 is at index 2. When I run what I have for finalIndexOf, I seem to enter an infinite loop of some sort, causing nothing to be returned because nothing happens so I have to manually terminate the program. Any help is appreciated!

```
private class Node<N extends Comparable<N>> {
    private N data;
    private Node<N> next;
}

protected Node<L> head;

public List() {
    head = null;
}

private Node<L> getLast() {
    Node<L> node = head;
    while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
    } 
    return node;
}

public int listSize() {
    if (head == null)
        return 0;
    int size = 0;
    for (Node<L> n = head; n != null; n = n.next)
        size++;
    return size;
}

public int finalIndexOf(L element)  {
    int index = listSize();
    Node<L> n = getLast();

    while (n != null) {
        if ((element == null) && (n.data == null))
            return index;
        if (n.data != null)
            if (n.data.compareTo(element) == 0)
                return index;
        index--;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Where you have specified type parameter `L`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through your list, as you have only next, you have to do it from the beginning to the end. If node value is the same as searched element, then assign current index to result, after iterating whole list return that result.

```
private int finalIndexOf(L element) {
    int index = 0;
    int result = -1;
    Node<L> node = head;
    while (node != null) {            
        if (node.data != null && node.data.compareTo(element) == 0) {
            result = index;
        }
        node = node.next;
        index++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite while loop because you never change the `n` variable of the loop condition in the loop.

Here's a hint: iterate the list from the first item to the last and return the index of the last match you find.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to go backwards from the end of the linked list, and return the index as soon as you hit a match. That's a good strategy, but you have no `node.prev`. You only have a singly linked list. Also, you're changing `index` in your while loop, but the value of n never changes. Try iterating from the head to the end instead, and reporting the index of the last time you find a match.